# iOS Objective-C - for-loop issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

The code below produces and error in the line `[myArray objectAtIndex:i];` and I can't seem to figure out why?

Any ideas?

```
int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
        int tempNumber = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        total = total + tempNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It could be because you are setting an object to an int.  By definition, objectAtIndex returns an object.

Depending on the type of object in myArray, you can try something like this:

```
int tempNumber = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't put `int`s into your array, then you need to do something extra to get `int`s out. If you're getting an error with your code above, then it's because you don't have `int`s in the array, and you need

```
int myInteger = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Or something to get the ints out of the array, depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: But they are not required to. Using some CoreFoundation magic, you can actually store primitives inside a NSArray.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - That sounds cool; how would one go about doing that?